# Unable to convert this class componenet to a functional component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scroll

this is my first time posting here also, I am very new to Javascript and React. Here, I have code of the react-infinite-scroll-component. I want to convert this class component to a functional component:

Class Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

const style = {
  height: 30,
  border: "1px solid green",
  margin: 6,
  padding: 8
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    items: Array.from({ length: 20 }),
    hasMore: true
  };

  fetchMoreData = () => {
    if (this.state.items.length >= 500) {
      this.setState({ hasMore: false });
      return;
    }
    // a fake async api call like which sends
    // 20 more records in .5 secs
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.concat(Array.from({ length: 20 }))
      });
    }, 500);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>demo: react-infinite-scroll-component</h1>
        <hr />
        <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={this.state.items.length}
          next={this.fetchMoreData}
          hasMore={this.state.hasMore}
          loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
          endMessage={
            <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
            </p>
          }
        >
          >
          {this.state.items.map((i, index) => (
            <div style={style} key={index}>
              div - #{index}
            </div>
          ))}
        </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I tried converting this to a functional component, but I failed. Please correct the errors in my code below:

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

const style = {
  height: 30,
  border: "1px solid green",
  margin: 6,
  padding: 8
};

function App() {
  const {items, hasMore} = useState(Array.from({ length: 20 }), true)


  fetchMoreData = () => {
    if (items.length >= 500) {
      setState({ hasMore: false });
      return;
    }
    // a fake async api call like which sends
    // 20 more records in .5 secs
    setTimeout(() => {
      setState({
        items: items.concat(Array.from({ length: 20 }))
      });
    }, 500);
  };

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>demo: react-infinite-scroll-component</h1>
        <hr />
        <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={items.length}
          next={fetchMoreData}
          hasMore={state.hasMore}
          loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
          endMessage={
            <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
            </p>
          }
        >
          >
          {state.items.map((i, index) => (
            <div style={style} key={index}>
              div - #{index}
            </div>
          ))}
        </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>
    );
  }




render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I understand that my code is full of errors and very dirty, but please excuse me, and thanks in advance!

Comment: The main issue here is the incorrect use of the useState hook, see the docs for reference https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import { React, useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

const style = {
  height: 30,
  border: "1px solid green",
  margin: 6,
  padding: 8
};

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(Array.from({ length: 20 }))
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true)


  fetchMoreData = () => {
    if (items.length >= 500) {
      setHasMore(false);
      return;
    }
    // a fake async api call like which sends
    // 20 more records in .5 secs
    setTimeout(() => {
      setItems(items.concat(Array.from({ length: 20 })));
    }, 500);
  };

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>demo: react-infinite-scroll-component</h1>
        <hr />
        <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={items.length}
          next={fetchMoreData}
          hasMore={hasMore}
          loader={<h4>Loading...</h4>}
          endMessage={
            <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
              <b>Yay! You have seen it all</b>
            </p>
          }
        >
          >
          {items.map((i, index) => (
            <div style={style} key={index}>
              div - #{index}
            </div>
          ))}
        </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>
    );
  }




render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, but it's giving an error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
` can you please help me out?

Comment: Try to use 'const' keyword while defining fetchMoreData function inside App function.